# Should I start breathing deep immediately starting a sprint

Tags: running, breathing, endurance, sprinting

After my warm up, I have a relatively low breathing rate. When I begin to sprint should I start breathing quickly and deeply immediately or wait until I'm just out of oxygen?

If I start deep breathing immediately I tend to get light-headed. If I start later on I tend to run out of breath quickly and have to stop to catch my breath.

Comment: How long of a sprint?

Comment: I think that you should take in as much oxygen as you can, as early as possible.  I don't think that world class sprinters avoid breathing heavily at the start of a race.

Comment: I really suggest you to look for co2 sensitivity, and bolt score.

Answer (score 1):

you should breath naturally and as calm as you can. even, if possible. of course as you begin to expend energy your breathing rate will increase as your heart rate increases. dont hold your breath